# Swift - How to return json object from an API call in Model to use in View Controller

Tags: ios, json, swift, callback

I am using REST api for showing some details in my application. For this i am planning to have a data model class to pass the datas back to the controller.

```
    import UIKit
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import Alamofire
class ContactUsModelClass {

    func getContactUsApiCall(URL: URL, callback: @escaping ((Dictionary<AnyHashable,Any>) -> ())) {
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<GetContactusResponse>) in
                print(response.result.value!)
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    // optional is NOT NULL, neither NIL nor NSNull
                    guard let end = response.result.value else {
                        return
                    }
                        //end = nullToNil(end.loginAuthenticationInfo?.accessToken)
                    callback(response.result.value)
                    break
                case .failure:
                    if let error = response.result.error as? URLError {
                        print("URLError occurred: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("Unknown error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                    }
                    break
                }
        }
    }


}
```

In My view controller i am trying to access it through:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //getContactUsApiCall(URL:contactusURL!as URL)
        getContactUsApiCall(URL:contactusURL!as URL) { dictionary in
            print(dictionary)
        }
```

But i am getting the following errors:

[image: ViewController Error]

[image: data model class error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are actually self-explanatory. `Use of unresolved id` means that the method you are calling is not in the current scope. Since `getContactUsApiCall` is actually declared inside the class `ContactUsModelClass`, you'll need to call it from an object of that class. Alternatively, you could modify the method to be a `class` method and call it as `ContactUsModelClass.getContactUsApiCall(...)`.

As for the second error, response.result.value is of the type `GetContactusResponse?`. Hence, your callback's signature should also use that type. Like so:

```
class func getContactUsApiCall(URL: URL, callback: @escaping ((GetContactusResponse) -> ())) {
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<GetContactusResponse>) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                // optional is NOT NULL, neither NIL nor NSNull
                guard let end = response.result.value else {
                    return
                }
                callback(end)
                break
            case .failure:
                if let error = response.result.error as? URLError {
                    print("URLError occurred: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Unknown error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                }
                break
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function instead

```
class func getContactUsApiCall(URL: URL, completionHandler: @escaping ((Dictionary<AnyHashable,Any>)->Void)) {
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON{ response in
            print(response.result.value!)
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                // optional is NOT NULL, neither NIL nor NSNull
                guard let end = response.result.value else {
                    return
                }
                //end = nullToNil(end.loginAuthenticationInfo?.accessToken)
                completionHandler(value as! Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>)//I would be careful here to make sure you data is returned in this format
                break
            case .failure:
                if let error = response.result.error as? URLError {
                    print("URLError occurred: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Unknown error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                }
                break
            }
    }
}
```

and then this is your view did load

```
ContactUsModelClass.getContactUsApiCall(URL:contactusURL!as URL, completionHandler: { (dictionary) -> Void in
     print(dictionary)
})
```

Hope that helps. If you are using the data in a view did load, you can put the call in the same VC.